# Create a knobInput widget in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, widget

I quickly tried to create a knob custom input widget in shiny, based on the  [jQuery knob library](http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/). Besides, I also adapted the [Rstudio tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html) to my specific case.
This is what I get [here](https://dgranjon.shinyapps.io/knobinput_example/).

The only way to change the input is to enter its value in the knob text input area. However, I would like this input to change when scrolling up or down as well as dragging with the mouse. How can I modify my code to achieve this goal?

Below are the js codes:

1. knob-input.R

   ```
   # This function generates the client-side HTML for a knob input
   knobInput <- function(inputId, label, value = NULL, min = 0, max = 100, 
                 angleArc = 360, angleOffset = 0, stopper = TRUE,
                 rotation = "clockwise", skin = "tron") {
     tagList(
       # This makes web page load the JS file in the HTML head.
       # The call to singleton ensures it's only included once
       # in a page.
       shiny::singleton(
         shiny::tags$head(
           shiny::tags$script(src = "jquery.knob.js"),
           shiny::tags$script(src = "knob-input-binding.js")
         )
       ),

       shiny::tags$label(label, `for` = inputId),
       shiny::tags$input(id = inputId, type = "text", value = value, class = "dial",
                 "data-value" = value,
                 "data-min" = min,
                 "data-max" = max,
                 "data-angleArc" = angleArc,
                 "data-angleOffset" = angleOffset,
                 "data-stopper" = stopper,
                 "data-rotation" = rotation,
                 "data-skin" = skin
                 )
     )
   }

   # Send an update message to a knob input on the client.
   # This update message can change the value and/or label.
   updateknobInput <- function(session, inputId,
                      label = NULL, value = NULL) {

     message <- dropNulls(list(label = label, value = value))
     session$sendInputMessage(inputId, message)
   }


   # Given a vector or list, drop all the NULL items in it
   dropNulls <- function(x) {
     x[!vapply(x, is.null, FUN.VALUE = logical(1))]
   }
   ```
2. knob-input-binding.js

   ```
   // Knob input binding

   var knobInputBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();


   // An input binding must implement these methods
   $.extend(knobInputBinding, {

     // This returns a jQuery object with the DOM element
     find: function(scope) {
      return $(scope).find('.dial');
     },

     // this method will be called on initialisation
     initialize: function(el){

        // extract the value from el
        // note here our knobInput does not yet exist
        var value = $(el).data("value");

        // initialize our knob based on the extracted state
        el.value = value;
     },

     // Given the DOM element for the input, return the value
     getValue: function(el) {
       return el.value;
     },

     // Set up the event listeners so that interactions with the
     // input will result in data being sent to server.
     // callback is a function that queues data to be sent to
     // the server.
     subscribe: function(el, callback) {
       $(el).on('keyup.knobInputBinding', function(event) {
         callback(true);
         // When called with true, it will use the rate policy,
         // which in this case is to debounce at 500ms.
       });

       $(el).on('change.knobInputBinding', function(event) {
         callback(false);
         // When called with false, it will NOT use the rate policy,
         // so changes will be sent immediately
       });
     },

     // Remove the event listeners
     unsubscribe: function(el) {
       $(el).off('.knobInputBinding');
     },

     // Receive messages from the server.
     // Messages sent by updateknobInput() are received by this function.
     receiveMessage: function(el, data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty('value'))
         this.initialize(el, data.value);

       if (data.hasOwnProperty('label'))
         $(el).parent().find('label[for="' + $escape(el.id) + '"]').text(data.label);

       $(el).trigger('change');
     },

     // This returns a full description of the input's state.
     // Note that some inputs may be too complex for a full description of the
     // state to be feasible.
     getState: function(el) {
       return {
         label: $(el).parent().find('label[for="' + $escape(el.id) + '"]').text(),
     value: el.value
       };
     },

     // The input rate limiting policy
     getRatePolicy: function() {
       return {
       // Can be 'debounce' or 'throttle'
         policy: 'debounce',
         delay: 500
       };
     }

   });

   Shiny.inputBindings.register(knobInputBinding, 'shiny.knobInput');
   ```
3. basic-knob.js

   ```
   $(function($) {
     $(".dial").knob();
   });
   ```

(If the third code snippet is not present, knobs are not rendered properly).

EDITS: here is the single file, shinyapp code

```
library(purrr)
source("knob-input.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Custom input example"),

  includeScript("www/basic-knob.js"),

  fluidRow(
    column(4, wellPanel(
      knobInput("knobval", "", value = 10),
      knobInput("knobval2", "", value = 20),
      actionButton("reset", "Reset Knob")
    )),
    column(8, wellPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("value")
    ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$value <- renderText({
    c(input$knobval, input$knobval2)
  })

  observe({
    # Run whenever reset button is pressed
    input$reset
    knobvec <- c("knobval", "knobval2")
    # Send an update to knobs, resetting their values
    map(knobvec, updateknobInput, session = session, value = 0)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My second question is: how can I change the skin used? For example, I would like to use the `data-skin="tron"`, like [in the jQuery knob showcase](http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code of your shiny app? we can try to capture the nob changed value in reactive and share it to your textOutput.

Comment: sure! I made an edit in my comment (the 3 javascript files should be in the /www directory and knob-input.R in the same directory as the single file app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knob has a special way to deal with events, to trigger change you can add in your subscribe method this code :

```
$(el).trigger('configure', {
  'change': function (v) {
     callback(false);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** there is not really a "tron" skin, this is manually implemented in draw parameter when initialized, you can change your `basic-knob.js` file with this :

```
$(function($) {
    $(".dial").knob({
        draw: function() {
            // "tron" case
            if (this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {
                this.cursorExt = 0.3;
                var a = this.arc(this.cv) // Arc
                    ,
                    pa // Previous arc
                    , r = 1;
                this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
                if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
                    pa = this.arc(this.v);
                    this.g.beginPath();
                    this.g.strokeStyle = this.pColor;
                    this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, pa.s, pa.e, pa.d);
                    this.g.stroke();
                }
                this.g.beginPath();
                this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor;
                this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, a.s, a.e, a.d);
                this.g.stroke();
                this.g.lineWidth = 2;
                this.g.beginPath();
                this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
                this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                this.g.stroke();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Here is the result: https://dgranjon.shinyapps.io/knobinput_example/. I would be glad if you could implement something better with shinyWidgets :)

Comment: Nice :). That's definitely something for shinyWidgets ! If i implement it, you'll be listed as collaborator, but i don't know when i'll be able to do it.. An other solution will be a pull request ;)